# Please explain the following contrast in grammaticality in syntax

Tags: syntax, english, grammaticality

> *Mary to be accepted at Boston College would be great.
>   For Mary to be accepted at Boston College would be great

Comment: Is this just a homework question?

Comment: Yes it is for homework

Comment: This could be an on-topic question, but it would need more context. What syntactic theory are you using, for one? What work have you done on it so far? Just plain homework questions on here are likely to get closed.

Comment: I see no contrast -- they're both grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

Because in English, to-infinitivals with an overt subject always require a subordinator *for*. See Huddleston (2002, pp. 1178-1181). Here is another example but in complement position:

> a) It would be strange for you to stop talking.
>
> b) *It would be strange you to stop talking.

Huddleston, R. (2002). 'Non-finite and verbless clauses.' From Huddleston, R. & Pullum, G. K. et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.* Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Edit: For the historical origin of the construction, please see my answer to [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/23092/how-do-you-assign-case-to-sentences-with-an-infinitval-clause/23093#23093).

Comment: Yes... but why?

Comment: Well, you don't generally find an answer to "why?" questions with syntax. In this case, when an infinitive complement clause appears as the subject of a sentence, and it's a **full** infinitive clause, with its own subject, as here, the infinitive complementizer _for...to_ is required in full -- i.e, the _for_, which marks the infinitive subject, (_to_ marks the verb phrase) is required -- because otherwise the addressee is likely to interpret the subject of the infinitive, instead of the infinitive complement itself, as the subject of the whole clause, It's preventive.

Comment: @jlawler. Are we talking about English, or some "universal" language laws? Off hand, I cannot think of a similar construction in any other language. Presumably this usage has a history?

Comment: @fdb. How would you describe the construction you are trying to match up? I don't see a construction, per se, just a minor restriction on one particular English complementizer. (not at all universal, btw -- definitely English stuff). Complementizers are used as syntactic markers for three of the four complement types in English: _for...to_ for infinitives, _-ing_ with optional possessive subject for gerunds, and _that_ for tensed complements. The parts of complementizers that are not inflections are often deleted, like anything predictable.

Comment: Chapter 14 (pp. 1178-1181 are from there) was written by Huddleston alone, not by Huddleston and Pullum, and the grammar itself was a collaborative project, with many linguists contributing to different chapters.

Comment: why questions in linguistics are the most important and imho most interesting. If a language theory cannot or does not purport to explain observable data (i.e. address why questions), then it ceases to be a real scientific enterprise and turns into a pastime for "admirers of languages".

Comment: @Araucaria tbh I was hesitant to change it because I wasn't sure if I should just correct the error or follow your original comment and revert it to the older version.

Comment: I've asked Geoffrey Pullum and he said that the correct way to refer to CGEL is "Huddleston, Rodney and Geoffrey K. Pullum, et al. (2002)". Incidentally, I've never claimed that Huddleston and Pullum were merely editors.

Comment: @AlexB. +1 Thanks for that - useful to refer to. You're right about the eds bit  - but that's what had crept into the post!